# Return top 20 largest numerical values w/o using sort or rank

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, rank

I have got large number of rows (say 10000+). Can I find the top 20 highest values (numerical) in it without using any sort or Rank function. For example by putting then in some kind of buckets etc.

Comment: I doubt that, have you tried something?

Comment: i dont knw im thinnking about it like coz if number of rows are really large it might take some time fr the system to compute and a single change in value related to it will strt the process again. im confused myself sorry.

Comment: i thought of putting a log fun. before the values and some value above a particular range will be marked as priority something

Comment: You can actually initiate the same sort mechanism via VBA, and provide a button to execute it. That way there are not formulae associated in the sheet. What say?

Comment: cant a formula be made to just knw what my top 20 values are they dont need to be in specific order.

Answer (score 1):

If your values are located in, say, range `A1:A10000` and you want to find the top 20 highest values and output these in, say, range `B1:B20`, you can do this by:

Select the range `B1:B20` and input the formula

```
=LARGE(A1:A10000,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A1:A10000))))
```

Because this is an array formula, end by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now have a dynamic list of the 20 largest values in `B1:B20`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LARGE(array,k). For your requirement, this might be suiting

> =LARGE(A:A,ROW($A1))

After entering this in a cell, drag and drop to the next 20 cells or more.